# How to edit all records of a Table in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following code:

```
for entry in db.session.query(MyTable):
  entry.fieldX = calculate(entry.fieldA, entry.fieldB, entry.fieldC)
  db.session.add(entry) ### IS this line required or is it implicit
db.session.commit()
```

Is it required to add to session explicitly? Is the following a better?

```
entries = []
for entry in db.session.query(MyTable):
  entry.fieldX = calculate(entry.fieldA, entry.fieldB, entry.fieldC)
  entries.append(entry)
db.session.add_all(entries)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: It's likely to be more efficient to generate an explicit update statement for the DBMS to execute, this will save your program the work of fetching each row and saving it again.  Can we see some details about the implementation of your `calculate()` function to see how that might be done?

Comment: @IfLoop Hmm. calculate actually uses other maps. so will not help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add your `entry` objects to the session, because they are already in the `session` which loaded them. So this suffice:

```
for entry in db.session.query(MyTable):
    entry.fieldX = calculate(entry.fieldA, entry.fieldB, entry.fieldC)
db.session.commit()
```